# SDWebImage Unrecognised Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am getting the following crash while displaying the image in cell.
UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbce1521e70" 
I followed all the instruction provided but still not able to get anything, I set the other linker flag`to`-Objc` but still getting the same error.

[reference image of cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKtJc.png)
My Code:

```
 UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@thumb_%@",kImageUrl,[dict objectForKey:@"student_photo"]]);


    [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@thumb_%@",kImageUrl,[dict objectForKey:@"student_photo"]]]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"not_found.png"]];
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Can you attach some of your code?

Comment: @satish I added

Comment: check your pod version of SDWebImage

Comment: Are you sure `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]` really is an `UIImageView`?

Comment: I dint use pod I copied the source file and it is the latest version

Comment: `img` is not an image for sure, check if `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]` really an `UIImageView`

Comment: @gereon I don't know I am new in objective-c

Comment: can you show the code of your custom cell?

Comment: the cell is created by storyboard , it is like the cell contains a content view and the content view have UIimage and UILabel

Comment: post the code from cell which contains label and image view.

Comment: also add screenshot of cell view hierarchy from story board.

Comment: it will help people to understand the cause.

Comment: I added the screenshot of the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the view that you get to avoid crash.

```
UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) { //it will true if img is kind of UIImageView

    [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@thumb_%@",kImageUrl,[dict objectForKey:@"student_photo"]]]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"not_found.png"]];
} else {
   NSLog(@"It is not an image view.")
}
```

**You need to set 'tag = 1' to your image view in `cell otherwise your image will never fill with an image.**

Comment: In the custom cell I need to set tag?

Comment: Yes, in cell you need to set like `cell.yourImageView.tag = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your crash log and code below

```
UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
```

The variable `img` might be nil or some other view. Double check your imageView's tag.

If everything is correct, check your cell xib(there should not be any error or warning in IBOutlet connection), if you've created a custom cell using xib.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to set ***"other linker flag"*** to ***"-ObjC"*** instead of ***"_Objc"***

It worked for me.

Comment: I have set to -Objc only